# django root url not working

Tags: django, apache, django-admin, django-templates, django-urls

When you go to my site austinhum.webfactional.com it goes to the admin console with the message of "You don't have permission to edit anything." I should mention that my base template is the base template of the admin console because I needed to incorporate the admin tools within the page. However, my url for the root page is a direct_to_template call

```
url(r'^$', direct_to_template,{'template':'index.html'}),
```

My index.html template (main.html extends base.html):

```
{% extends "main.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="homePage">  
    <div><img id="splashImage" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/BBBSL2.jpg"</div>    
    </div>  
    <div class="clear"></div>
{% endblock %}
```

I have other pages that are using direct_to_template without any problems. On my local machine the homepage shows up without a problem. Is this some sort of apache setting I'm not aware of? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried actually logging in on your production site? I would think including anything from the admin templates will impose django permissions on you.

Comment: Yes, this occurs while I'm logged in as well as when I'm not. If I remove that line from my urls.py, it still goes to the same page making me believe it's not even seeing the template. It is the first url listed to ensure it gets checked first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I had copied the 'index.html' file from admin into my project and that was conflicting with my own 'index.html'

Comment: wow. I can't believe I spent hours to find out why my setup was not working as well. Thanks!